# Como capturar o elemento único no HTML?

Tags: html

Minha dúvida é um pouco confusa, mas espero ser o mais claro possível.
Como mostra na imagem ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lafjw.png ) eu tenho um carrinho e a div de cada elemento (produto) possui o mesmo id, uma vez que ela é o modelo e todos os outros produtos usarão a mesma estrutura.
O problema é que quando adiciono um item no primeiro produto (arroz) todos os produtos sofrem a adição, já que utilizam o mesmo ID, e no javascript o comando acontece utilizando o ID. 
Seria possível gerar um ID diferente toda vez que um novo produto for adicionado no carrinho? Como se fosse a chave primaria de um banco de dados.

HTML de um dos itens do carrinho:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="modeloProdutos">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- descrição produtos + imagem -->
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
                            <img src="img/arroz.jpg">
                            Arroz integral tipo C 5KG Arroz integral tipo C 5KG Arroz integral tipo C 5KG Arroz integral tipo C 
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <!-- informar quantidade de produtos -->
                            <div class="container-fluid" id="divAddProdutosPagamentos">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <!-- Botão de subtrair -->
                                    <!-- nao consigo redimensionar o botao -->
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend col-lg-3" id="buttonMinus">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Campo p/ informar a qtd-->
                                    <!-- aqui vai setado a quantidade de itens informado no index -->
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-group-prepend col-lg-3" id="inputQtd" 
                                    value="0">

                                    <!-- Botão de adicionar -->
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend col-lg-3" id="buttonAdd">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- FIM DA DIV ADD PRODUTO -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            R$ 23.11
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            R$ 43.44 
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#buttonAdd').click (function(){
    count++
    $('#inputQtd').val(count);
    $('#badgeCarrinho').text(count);
  });
});
```

PS: badgeCarrinho é uma notificação ao lado do ícone do carrinho, no canto superior direito (onde 4)

Comment: Não se usa o mesmo id para mais de um elemento. Um id deve ser único. Use class em vez de id.

Comment: Não daria o mesmo efeito por conta do `this`.

Comment: Entendi o que quis dizer, acreditava que o this funcionava para o ID tambem, perdoe minha ignorancia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como capturar o elemento único no HTML?

Um id deve ser único em uma página. Esse erro é muito comum por aqui, porque as pessoas não sabem bem o seu uso. O próprio nome do atributo indica que ele deve ser único: id é uma IDentidade de alguma coisa, logo, o termo "identidade" indica que algo que possui essa identidade só ele a possui. Seria como um número de CPF ou até de RG, onde cada cidadão tem o seu. Imagine duas ou mais pessoas terem o mesmo CPF, que confusão que não daria!

Já a classe (atributo `class`) um ou mais elementos podem ter o mesmo. Fazendo uma analogia, uma ou mais pessoas podem ser careca, isso seria a classe, mas a identidade de cada um é diferente:

```
João: é careca e possui o CPF 1234
Pedro: é careca e possui o CPF 4567
```

Seria:

João e Pedro possuem a classe "careca", mas cada um tem o seu CPF único.

No caso do JavaScript, você pode pegar o elemento pela classe usando o `this`. O `this` dentro do evento representa o elemento que disparou o evento. No seu caso, teria que trocar o `#buttonAdd` por uma classe `.buttonAdd`:

```
<div class="input-group-prepend col-lg-3" class="buttonAdd">
```

E o mesmo para o input da quantidade, trocando `id="inputQtd"` para `class="inputQtd"`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-group-prepend col-lg-3" class="inputQtd" 
                                value="0">
```

E no jQuery alterar o seletor para classe e buscar dentro da div `.row` (o botão de adicionar e o input de quantidade estão dentro da mesma div `.row`) o elemento que possui a classe `.inputQtd` usando `.closest()` e `.find()` para:

```
$('.buttonAdd').click(function(){
   count++
   $(this).closest('.row').find('.inputQtd').val(count);
   $('#badgeCarrinho').text(count);
});
```

Da mesma forma, troque o `id="divAddProdutosPagamentos"` para classe: `class="divAddProdutosPagamentos"`, onde você pode usar no `.closest()` para achar o input da quantidade:

```
$('.buttonAdd').click(function(){
   count++
   $(this).closest('.divAddProdutosPagamentos').find('.inputQtd').val(count);
   $('#badgeCarrinho').text(count);
});
```

No caso de incrementar cada quantidade de forma independente, não use a variável `count` para esses inputs. Você fará desta forma, pegando o valor do input e somando +1:

```
$('.buttonAdd').click(function(){

   var iqtd = $(this).closest('.divAddProdutosPagamentos').find('.inputQtd');
   var qtd = Number(iqtd.val());

   iqtd.val(qtd+1);
   $('#badgeCarrinho').text(count);
});
```

Comment: Tanto faz antes ou depois.

Comment: Cara... funcionou. Eu nao conhecia as funçoes de closest, find e tudo mais, entao vou ter que estudar esse codigo pra ver como ele funciona. No caso desse exemplo, voce usou a classe 'row' pq os elementos que vc usou estavam dentro dela?

Comment: Sim. O closest() busca o elemento pai mais próximo onde os elementos estão dentro. O find() busca qualquer elemento filho que estiver dentro. É bem simples.

Comment: Entendi... nao querendo abusar da sua boa vontade, mas poderia me ajudar em mais uma duvida? O meu count continua sendo usado por todos os campos, exemplo: no primeiro campo valia 4, portanto no segundo campo ele continua a partir dai (5, 6 e 7). Teria como eu torna-lo unico tambem?

Comment: Sim. Neste caso vc não teria que usar a variável count. Esqueça ela. Vc incrementa a quantidade buscando o valor do campo .inputQtd e soma +1.

Comment: Acrescentei na resposta. Veja se era isso que queria.

Comment: O senhor me salvou de muitas madrugadas de insonia, muito obrigado!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar. Tmj!